# The background advertised peripheral to be scanned from other BLE devices either in foreground/background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on with `BLE` of `iOS` where in i could able to establish a peripheral advertisement and scanning at the same time.

I have 2 devices where in both would scan advertise at the same time, it works fine when the devices are in foreground.

Now the issue is: The device is in background meaning the advertisement is not working(not able to show the Local Name and UUID as it will mask as per Apple) because as per [Apple Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1) 
`advertisement key are placed in a special “overflow” area; they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them.`

**Now my question how can i scan for this overflow area?**

Also note when a device is advertising in background i do not get a call back in below delegate too:
`- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;`

Any possible way i can do this approach, which would really helpful.

Comment: As long as the scanning device is an iOS device you don't need to do anything except scan for the specific service you are advertising on the other side.

Comment: @Paulw11 I cannot be scan for that particular device.
And there is a specific which apple mentioned, `they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them.`

Comment: Yes. Explicitly scanning for them means you have specified the service uuid in your scan request, that's all.

Comment: Yes @Paulw11 What u have said i correct.
The only way to do that is using just mention the `ScanForPeripherals` by passing the service UUID.

And that worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to the above scenario is as per @Paulw11 said.
We just need to scan for specific Peripheral Id.
Thanks Paulw11